# How to use Scanner to change web contents in java

Tags: java

I want to change a website's content by using scanner. It works perfectly well if the original String is just several lines. But when I change the string into the website's contents, the code does not work. It gives me the original web contents.
Here is my code:

```
public static void main (String args[]){
    String original = getWebContents(url);
    Scanner in = new Scanner (original);
    in.useDelimiter("[^\\p{Alpha}']+");
    int i = 1;
    String changed="";
    while (in.hasNext()){
        String word = in.next();
        if (word.equals("'")) // ignore lone apostrophes
            continue;

        if (word.length() >= 3 && word.endsWith("s") && word.charAt(word.length() - 2) == 'r'
                && word.charAt(word.length() - 3) == 'a') {
            word = word.replaceAll("r", "h");

        }
        if (word.length() >= 3 &&
                word.endsWith("r") && word.charAt(word.length() - 3) == 'e' &&
                word.charAt(word.length() - 2) == 'e') {
            word = word.replaceAll("r", "y") + "ah";
        }
        if (word.length() >= 2 && word.endsWith("r") && word.charAt(word.length() - 2) == 'i'
                && word.charAt(word.length() - 2) != word.charAt(word.length() - 3)) {
            word = word.replaceAll("r", "h");
        }
        if (word.length() >= 3 && word.endsWith("r")
                && word.charAt(word.length() - 2) == 'o'
                && word.charAt(word.length() - 3) == 'o') {
            word = word.replaceAll("r", "w") + "ah";
        }
        if (word.length() >= 2 && word.endsWith("r") && word.charAt(word.length() - 2) == 'a') {
            word = word.replaceAll("r", "h");
        }
        if (word.length() >= 3 && word.endsWith("r") && word.charAt(word.length() - 2) == 'e'
                && word.charAt(word.length() - 3) != 'e') {
            word = word.replaceAll("r", "h");
        }
        if (word == "very"){
            word=word.replaceAll(word,"wicked");
        }
        if (word.length()>1 && word.endsWith("a")){
            word=word+'r';
        }
        changed +=word;
        i++;



    }
    System.out.println(String.format("%s,%s", original,changed));
}
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help you without knowing what's the content of `original` ? further,  "the code does not work" is very vague: what doesn't work? does it produce an output you weren't expecting? does it crash? does it print an error? stacktrace? which line fails?

Comment: It may be better to post also some examples when it is worked and not worked. Generally, I see you compare `String` using `==`, which should be always wrong.

Comment: try debugging it

Comment: ...What are you doing?  Why are you doing this?  What is your ultimate aim with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> It gives me the original web contents.

The problem is this line:

`System.out.println(String.format(original,changed));`

You are not providing a format string, instead you are passing the `original` string as the format string. This is why you are seeing only the `original` printed to `System.out`.

Take a look at the [documentation of this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) and make sure you use it correctly.